# Plotting the inverse of non elementary functions on tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote

While working on a physics problem (a certain version of the simple pendulum), I was able to solve the equation of motion to get the following result:

[image]

I would like to plot theta(t) on tikz (for a fixed value of the length l and the max angle theta_max,  of course), preferably without having to generate a list of values on a separate program. The integral is improper for theta=theta_max which may pose additional difficulties. I would also like to know if there's an easy way to animate this pendulum with the animate package (I know how to animate a pendulum with angle theta(t) if I have the explicit expression, but not in this case). Any help, please?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! First you need to solve math problem (which is not topic of this site), than you we can help you (with some effort) to draw, what you like to have.

Comment: If you can plot `theta(t)`, all you need to do to plot `t(theta)` is to swap the roles of x and y, i.e. swap the components in a parametric plot. That is, instead of `(t,{theta(t)})` plot `({theta(t)},t)`.

Comment: when ever you can draw the graph of y=f(x) with `\draw \yourpath; ` ,then you can draw the inverse function with `\draw[rotate=-45,xscale=-1,rotate=45] \yourpath]`.

Comment: What is your desired static picture?

Comment: @TrongVuong1998 what do you mean by that? It's a relativistic simple pendulum (so l should be in light seconds and g should be in ls/s^2), but aside from that it's just a normal pendulum

Comment: @azetina: Does the units on the right match those on the left?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like
the `Asymptote` would be a more suitable tool in this case,
since it has
a built-in function

```
real simpson(real f(real), real a, real b, real acc=realEpsilon, real dxmax=b-a)
```

which returns the integral of `f` from `a` to `b` using adaptive Simpson integration.

```
// inv-int-graph.asy
//
// run 
//    asy inv-int-graph.asy
// to get a standalone inv-int-graph.pdf
//
settings.tex="pdflatex";
import graph;
import math;

real pagew=9cm,pageh=0.618*pagew;
size(pagew,pageh,IgnoreAspect);

import fontsize;defaultpen(fontsize(7.5pt));
texpreamble("\usepackage{lmodern}"+"\usepackage{amsmath}"
+"\usepackage{amsfonts}"+"\usepackage{amssymb}");

pen linePen=darkblue+  0.7bp;

real scx=0.5, scy=0.05;
int xCells=19, yCells=13;
add(shift(-2*scx,-2*scy)*scale(scx,scy)*grid(xCells,yCells,paleblue+0.2bp));
real xmin=0,xmax=8.5;
real ymin=0,ymax=0.53;
xaxis("$t$",xmin,xmax,RightTicks(Step=1,step=0.5),above=true);
yaxis("$\theta$",ymin,ymax,LeftTicks (Step=0.1,step=0.05),above=true);

typedef pair pairFreal(real);

// Assuming that `g` is the acceleration due to gravity
// with the default value `9.8 m/s^2`.

pairFreal F(real L, real theta_max, real g=9.8){
  real f(real theta){return L/(1-exp(g*(theta^2-theta_max^2)))^(1/2);};
  return new pair(real phi){return (simpson(f,0,phi), phi);};
}

real L,theta_min,theta_max;
L=12; 
theta_max=pi/6;
theta_min=0;
real eps=1e-8;

guide gf=graph(F(L,theta_max),theta_min,theta_max-eps,n=100,operator..);
draw(gf,linePen);
label("$\theta(t)$",relpoint(gf,0.5),plain.NW);
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! That is beautiful. Is there an asymptote manual?

Comment: @azetina: Of course. Their official cite: [http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net),
It's part of the standard TeXLive distribution, so you can run `texdoc asymptote` and the manual must show up.
Thera are also many questions tagged [asymptote] on this TeX.SE site.

Comment: That looks great! Mind you, it was a relativistic problem so l would need to be in light seconds and g in ls/s^2

Comment: @azetina: I hope you can adjust the constants as needed. Just one remark on the formula:
it looks that it lacks something, since the argument of the exponential function must be unitless,
otherwise it does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Functions in integral form can be rewritten in differential form and solved as an initial value problem, using `\pstODEsolve` (RKF45) from the PSTricks `pst-ode` package:

```latex
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1cm,12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-ode,pst-plot}
\usepackage{xfp}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Function integral
% #1: theta (input)
% #2: PS variable for result list (output)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\def\F(#1)#2{%     two output points are enough---v   v---y[0](0) (initial value)
  \pstODEsolve[algebraicAll]{retVal}{y[0]}{0}{#1}{2}{0.0}{\L/sqrt(1-Euler^(\g*(t^2-\thetaMax^2)))}
  %         integration interval theta=0---^   ^---"theta"
  %
  %  initialise empty solution list given as arg #2, if necessary
  \pstVerb{/#2 where {pop}{/#2 {} def} ifelse}
  %  From `retVal', we throw away y(theta=0), and append `y(theta) theta' to our
  %  solution list (arg #2):
  \pstVerb{/#2 [#2 retVal exch pop #1] cvx def}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\def\L{12}
\edef\thetaMax{\fpeval{pi/6}}
\def\g{9.8}

% solve function integral for a number of plotpoints
\multido{\rTheta=0.0+\fpeval{\thetaMax/100}}{101}{
  \F(\rTheta){thetaOverTime} %results appended to solution list `thetaOverTime'
}

%plot result
\begin{psgraph}[xAxisLabel=$t$,yAxisLabel=$\theta$,ticksize=6pt,
  Dx=1,Dy=0.1](0,0)(8.5,0.55){0.8\linewidth}{0.45\linewidth}
  \listplot{thetaOverTime}
\end{psgraph}

\end{document}
```

[image]